# How to change an attribute value for all entries of ldap directory using ldapmodify command?

Tags: ldap, openldap, opends

LDAP: How to modify an attribute value for all entries of directory using ldapmodify command? Looking for some syntax like below in modification input file for ldapmodify command

dn: uid=*,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: customerNumber
customerNumber: 12345
-
add: accountNumber
accountNumber: 12345

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to query and modify entries in the one operation, though I'd like to be corrected.

Comment: @Andy Agreed, it isn't possible. OP will have to traverse the DIT.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done with just ldapmodify, but you can string a couple things together to do what you're asking. The following runs ldapmodify against an ldif file that we build on the fly from an ldapsearch plus the desired modifications.

```
ldapmodify -f <(ldapsearch -LLL -b ou=People,dc=example,dc=com -s one uid=* dn | sed 's/^$/add: customerNumber\ncustomerNumber: 12345\n-\nadd: accountNumber\naccountNumber: 12345\n-\n/' )
```

Note: This is gives all matched entries the same customerNumber and accountNumber. If that's not what you want you'll have to use something more complicated than `sed`, perhaps `awk` or `perl`. Also, it's probably complicated enough that you'll want to do it in more than one line first. Make the ldif, review, then run ldapmodify.